# Avoid data race worker with golang

Tags: go, data-race

I have a jobWorker which should deal with jobs and in this worker had database read write, log file, receive api and some data computing.

```
var mystruct strcut{}

func worker(v) {
   Get data from database
   ...
   Update database status
   ...
   useByWorker()
   ...
   Do some computing
   ...
   Receive API
   ...
   Write log file
}

func useByWorker() {
    mystruct = {1,2,3}
}
```

Here is my main func to run go-worker.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    data := [][]string{}
    wg.Add(1)
    for k,v := range data {
        k := k
        v := v
        go func(k int, v []string) {
            fmt.Println(k,v)
            worker(v)
            wg.Done()
        }(k, v)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Data race problem let the log and my data used in worker mix up. Any way can simply fix data race problem without lock(Mutex.Lock). I want jobs can be deal by worker faster.

Any suggestions or tips will helps. Thanks.

Comment: Your use of WaitGroup in the `main` is suspicious - you only call `Add(1)` once but then call `Done` multiple times (for each element in the `data`) in the goroutine.

Comment: "I want jobs can be deal by worker faster." --- do you seriously think few nanoseconds would make any of your code slower?

Comment: Time consume at waiting API or DB response. The main problem of this question is that how should I do these jobs in the same time and independently without data race.

Answer (score 1):

If you want non-blocking write access to file you can use one goroutine to write in file passing messages by channel. Blocks may be avoided by using [Channel Buffering](https://gobyexample.com/channel-buffering)
Or you can use [standard logger](https://golang.org/pkg/log/). It can work with multiple goroutines.